# Export ADF to Tango sdcard with Nash/Unity - ADF write permission denied

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I am working with Unity 5 and the Tango and trying to get the Area Learning Sample Code (Nash) to export the ADF to the SD card.
The error in logcat I get is:

```
I/tango_client_api(  195): Tango Service: saveAreaDescriptionMetadata, internal status 0
W/tango_client_api(  195): The application 'com.projecttango.experiments.unityarealearning' has no ADF import/export permissions. Instead of calling import/export through the Tango Service API, call the import/export Android intent.
I/tango_client_api(  195): Tango Service: exportAreaDescription, internal status -6
E/tango   (  195): TangoServer.cc:309 Export Area Description has no permission.
E/tango_client_api( 9873): TangoErrorType TangoService_exportAreaDescription(const char*, const char*): Internal Error: Could not export the ADF: 95f406fa-f24f-41bc-9355-5abd0db68c14 into folder: /sdcard/defaultArea.
I/Unity   ( 9873): PoseProvider.ExportAreaDescription() Could not export area description: 95f406fa-f24f-41bc-9355-5abd0db68c14
I/Unity   ( 9873):  
I/Unity   ( 9873): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebug.gen.cpp Line: 56)
I/Unity   ( 9873):
```

It seems like I have to replicate this Intent-based permission for exporting and importing, not just ADF loading and saving (see: https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/java-user-permissions)

But in C# Unity, and I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, because I work with C not Unity. Could it be you didn't set the permissions in the Android Manifest? You possible need to set writing permissions for your application.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Setting > Player setting > other settings, make sure write access is set to "External (SD card)"

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

https://github.com/chucknology/TangoSDfix/blob/master/README.md

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was create an Android library an call the `RequestImportExportActivity`. Like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26791889/3002676).

You can see how to do it [here](http://goo.gl/lFuUEs).